# Second element in each loop returns undefined

Tags: jquery

From fields with the class `.edit-links` i´m able to retrieve the values but  `$(this).next(".edit-url").val();` only returns the first found element then only returns undefined. In the console i can see that "this" is targeting the first element as expected but the second .edit-url is not found and returning prevObject.

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
  edit.revertLink();
});

var edit = {};
edit.revertLink = function() {

  $('.edit-link').each(function(index) {

    var currentName = $(this).val();
    var url = $(this).attr('data-tempurl');
    var meta = $(this).attr('data-meta');
    //edit.changeLiOrgname(this, currentName);

    if (meta === "external") {
      //url = $(this).next(".edit-url").val();
      currentName = $(this).next(".edit-url").val();
      //edit.changeLiOrgURL(this, url);
      $(".edit-url").remove();
    }

    var linkStr = [
      '<a href="' + url + '" class="aktiv">',
      '' + currentName + '',
      '<span class="type float-r">',
      '' + meta + '',
      '</span>',
      '</a>'
    ];

    $(".removeBtn").remove();
    $(this).replaceWith(linkStr.join(''));

  });
}
```

```html
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<li data-identifier="4.3e43f44714869abce3fabc5">
  <input class="edit-link" data-meta="internal" data-tempurl="/internal-page.html" type="text" value="Stöd">
</li>
<li>
  <input class="edit-link" data-meta="external" type="text" value="Link">
  <input class="edit-url" type="text" data-tempurl="www.link.se" value="www.link.se">
</li>
<li>
  <input class="edit-link" data-meta="external" type="text" value="link2">
  <input class="edit-url" type="text" data-tempurl="www.link2.se" value="www.link2.se">
</li>
<li>
  <input class="edit-link" data-meta="external" type="text" value="link3">
  <input class="edit-url" type="text" data-tempurl="www.lin3k.se" value="www.link3.se">
</li>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/stuffoak/pen/zvjOgM?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error here

```
$(".edit-url").remove();
```

in this line you remove **all** element with class *edit-url* but need remove just one, for current element.

You can change it to

```
$(this).next(".edit-url").remove();
```

or, just call it *after loop*

```
edit.revertLink = function() {

    $('.edit-link').each(function(index) {
      ...
    });
    $(".edit-url").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this condition

```
  if (meta === "external") {
     //url = $(this).next(".edit-url").val();
     currentName = $(this).next(".edit-url").val();
     //edit.changeLiOrgURL(this, url);
    $(".edit-url").remove();
  }
```

you are removing all `.edit-url` when ur meta is external so the next link doesnt find its edit-url. you should do this instead.

```
$(this).parent().find(".edit-url").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all `edit-url`. Try like following.

```
$(this).next(".edit-url").remove();
```

instead of

```
$(".edit-url").remove();
```

[CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adBGVX)